# C++ iterator "remove-proof"

Tags: c++, iterator, observer-pattern

I don't know if there are special keywords for what I need. I'm writing a basic [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and I'm concerned about some issues. My implementation is classical. I'm using a std::set of observers and whenever i need to fire an event, i iterate through this set and call the notify method of each of the observers. My problem is the following. What happen when the observable objects sends an event to the observers if:

- one observer wants to remove itself (or any other observer) from the observer set during the event ?
- one observer wants to clear the observer set (removing all of the observers) ?
- one observer destroy the observable object ?

I know all those cases will eventually happen. I have ideas for the third one, but this is off-topic. For the first and second case, the problem is that removing or clearing the std::set will invalidate the iterator i'm using to enumerate observables. Even if it doesn't, the observable shouldn't notify any observer which would have been removed during the event processing.

I didn't find yet an implementation of a set which provide an iterator capable of remaining valid when any item is removed. It would be possible to implement it though, at a cost of some indirection and storing in the container any reference to an alive iterator to update it when necessary.

Another solution would be to copy the set of observer, iterate the copy and check if the currently iterated observer is still in the true set. (This would forget any new observer added during the event but this case i don't care)

Do you have any suggestion/solutions about this problem ?

Comment: Instead of having the observers delete themselves, you could have them mark themselves as "todelete" and have the code that iterates do the actual deletion when it encounters an observer so marked.

Comment: @StevenBurnap That brings up a semantic issue: does the deletion have effect immediately, or at the end of this observation? For example, if Observer4 deletes Observer6, does Observer6 still get notified of the current event?

Comment: Ah...I didn't read closely enough and assumed observers only delete themselves.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Good point, but the usual observer pattern doesn't notify observers in any specific order (and the fact that he's using a `set` instead of an insertion-order container like `vector` suggests that's the intention here too), meaning the only reliable way to handle deletion is after all observers have been notified.

Comment: My problem is when an observer deletes the observable. If an observer deletes another observers, I assume that the deleted observer have the responsability of removing himfself from the set during his destruction. Which fall back into the first problem : what to do when one observer remove another observer from the set of active observers ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you're storing pointers or something in the container, and not actually the observer objects themselves. Because you obviously can't have observer code deleting the observer object!

std::set simply can't be used when you need to modify the set while you have iterators alive. It's just not what it's for.

If you need to remove things from the container, you could try returning a value from the event routine that tells the caller (the code that has the iterator) to remove that observer from the container. The that code can remove the thing the iterator is pointing at and continue properly along the sequence.

If you need to add things, don't add them directly to the container. Instead, add them to a queue, and have the code firing the events add the new stuff in after it completes iterating through the container.

If the container has a small number of objects, and the objects are small (pointers) I'd probably just copy the container and iterate over the copy. That way, the observers can muck with the container all they want without screwing up the iterators.

Comment: Actually, `std::set<>` has pretty good iterator invalidation semantics for this use case.  The only problem case is when you have an iterator that points to the item being removed.  OP's problem is that this iterator is a local variable and another function is invoked to remove the observer.

Answer (score 1):

Have the observer's notification method accept an iterator which points to that observer, and return an iterator which points to the next observer:

```
// PSEUDO-CODE not to be taken literally.

class normalObserver : public Observer {
  iterator notify(iterator me) { 
    assert(*me == this); 
    // do stuff
    return ++me;
  }
 };

 class deleteMeObserver : public Observer {
   iterator notify(iterator me) {
    assert(*me == this); 
     // do stuff
     object.observers.erase(me++);
     return me;
   }
 };

 class deleteEveryObserver :public Observer {
   iterator notifiy(iterator me) {
    assert(*me == this); 
     // do stuff
     object.observers.clear();
     return object.observers.end();
   }
};

 class Object {
   set::set<Observer*> observers;
   void notifyObservers() {
     for(it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); ) {
       it = (*it)->notify(it);
     }
   }
 };
```

Comment: In `deleteMeObserver::notify()`, should `it` be `me`instead?

Comment: And `erase()` doesn't return an iterator ... fixed.

Comment: This will work, but is not friendly with observers. I didn't mention that in my case, the observers are the users of the library i'm writing. Thus, i'm not really confortable with this solution.

Comment: Then I'd follow the advice elsewhere about having the observer return something to the object which carries instructions about what to do next: `enum NotificationResult { Normal, DeleteMe, DeleteSomeOtherGuy, DeleteEveryone }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment using `std::list` instead of `set`, because this way iterator won't get invalidated when  you remove elements unless it removed itself of course.

You can handle observer wanting to remove itself by keeping pointer (smart pointer or perhaps even weak pointer preferably) toward the observer object instead of iterator (this way when it removes itself, the pointer won't be invalidated (as long as it is smart and does not delete itself as well))

Comment: I believe list and set will have the same problems if you remove objects *while* iterating over the container. The iterator you hold might be invalidated, and then you are lost.

Comment: Actually, `std::set<>` has pretty good iterator invalidation semantics for this use case. The only problem case is when you have an iterator that points to the item being removed. OP's problem is that this iterator is a local variable and another function is invoked to remove the observer.

Comment: @BoPersson list is good at removing objects while iterating over the container as long as you are careful the return value of `list::erase` to be assigned as the next value of the iterator (not using ++it e.i. not working with the deleted iterator)

Comment: @AndréCaron Then you can use smart pointer (as I mentioned). Iterator is technically like a pointer. Or Rob's solution or Michael's are good.

Comment: @tozka - There is  a problem if the list (or set) contains pointers to functions, and those functions can remove elements from the container. I believe that is what the OP is attempting.

Comment: @tozka: using a weak/smart pointer to the object has nothing to do with the problem.  The problem is that while the `notify_observers()` function is executing and holding an iterator to the current observer, the `remove_observer()` function may be called, but it can't access local functions in the `notify_observers()` function.

Comment: @tozka: sorry, should have read "can't access local *variables* in the `notify_observers()` function".

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the observers direct access to the set. Let them do modifications through a method that has access to both the set and the iterator, which should be incremented before the observer is called. This method can check to see if the item at the iterator is being removed and increment it if so. For the remove all case, just set the iterator to `end()`.

Comment: I'm not actually giving access to the set. I'm only providing three methods : addObserver, removeObserver and clearObservers. Your solution requires to store the iterator in the observable insteaf of having it in the stack. Wouldn't be too much trouble i guess.